# downloading ppt format in rails using powerpoint ruby gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**1st Part:**
I Have implemented powerpoint gem in rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.2

I am just trying to download a html.erb file in pptx format

My codes like this:

@filters = generate_filters_for_manual_report(params)

@deck = Powerpoint::Presentation.new

title = 'Bicycle Of the Mind'

subtitle = 'created by Steve Jobs'

@deck.add_intro title, subtitle

@deck.save('/home/sahil/test6.pptx')

send_data @deck,  :filename => '/home/sahil/test6.pptx', 
   :disposition => 'inline', :type => "multipart/related"

it is getting saved in local directory as a pptx file. but unbable to downlaod as as pptx file.

**Part2**

the above is for text how Can i implement so that html.erb file for customer details and customer image  will be show in pptx slider.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Thanks @peter a lot for yr help. now send_file is working. but the issue is here i am using some static data with with @deck variable. how I will  add my .html.erb  file contents (with text and image) to @deck variable. I have so many images and texts . Also its getting saved in local directory as a pptx file format(In the above case as"/home/sahil/test6.pptx"). I dont want to save in local directory . I need to send directly in send file

Comment: Did you try to use `send_file` instead of `send_data`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for yr help. now send_file is working.

Comment: If you don't mind I will post it as answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `send_file` instead of `send_data`.

Comment: I didn't work with the gem so I can said with 100% sure but I think it can't be done. The gem allows you to create `.pptx` file, it's not convert tool. Also I don't understand why do you have `.html.erb` and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I have previous 50 cusomer details with description and image in html.erb file  which is rendering on html request. Now I want to download those customer details and images descriptions as pptx files                                        how I will add so many costumer details and images  and their descriptions in @deck onject which is object of PowerPoint::Presentation.new

Comment: As I sad I didn't use the gem. I think you should do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize powerpoint gem according to your need .

clone gem at this url [powerpoint gem](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/powerpoint)

put it into ur vender folder.

In your gem file change like this:
 gem "powerpoint", path: "vendor/powerpoint"

so that it will call methods of gem from vender folder and you can do customisation in your vender folder according to your need.

you can get all metods here: [presentation method](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/powerpoint/blob/master/lib/powerpoint/presentation.rb)

you can call multiple methods like this :
@deck.add_pictorial_slide title, image_path
@deck.add_text_picture_slide title, image_path, content

You can increase sliders with loop like this:

def add_pictorial_slide(title, image_path, coords = {})

```
  (1..5).each do |i|

     @slides << Powerpoint::Slide::Pictorial.new(presentation: self,title:title, image_path: image_path, coords: coords)

 end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

I have used it recently and had to [customize](https://github.com/dhyan/powerpoint/tree/customize-text-slide) it as per my need. Guess you already have it resolved. For problems related to having it saved on local file-system, i had to upload it to s3 and then use `send_data` for the download part. Using `tempfile`, i didn't have to worry much about storing/deleting these ppt files manually from the local file-system. Hope that helps!